# Move title before image in Category display (in Blog mode) of Articles

Tags: overrides

Created a new website using Joomla v4 and its Cassiopeia template (latest version).

The Articles displayed on the Category pages (in Blog mode) now show the image first and then the title. I'd like to have that the other way around: first the title and then the image -- just like it is when displaying the full Article (where the image is placed after the title, date/by-line and Tags).

I assume I have to override the PHP file that displays the "Article intros for a Category in Blog mode", but which one is that? (assuming the rest is a simple matter of rearranging the items in that PHP file)

E.g. see here for the current layout of Categories:
https://offerman.industries/projects

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can go into the Template and create an override for component com_content and that will create the files for you to then edit, in your case you are looking for `blog_item.php`.

[image]

Comment: Creating the override using the Template interface didn't copy the 'blog_item.php' file, only some other files. So I copied the file 'components/com_content/tmpl/category/blog_item.php' by hand to 'templates/cassiopeia/html/com_content/category/'. Editing this file got the job done.

Comment: Not sure why the files didn't get copied for you, the files you see in the screen shot are what get created/copied when I selected them from the 'Create Overrides' tab.
Please select the answer so that we know this issue has been resolved.